# How can I withdraw the ETH that I sent to the Etherscan contract that I created

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, scam

I did something stupid and think it may have been a scam. Part of the scam was for me to create our own etherscan contract and send ETH there where an arbitrage bot would trade it. The bot was connected to our metamask wallet.

The one thing working in my favour is that my metamask wallet was basically empty anyway so no crypto has been taken. However some staked FLR and Songbird is staked through that metamask.

My question is- Is it possible for me to get that ETH i sent to etherscan back? Since I created the contract?

Also, Is it possible my metamask wallet is now hacked with a drainer software? When I unstake my cryptos will they instantyl drain?.

Here is the youtube video of the hack in question

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhdrjOFT-E8&t=2s`

Any advice is greatly appreciated¬!! Thanks for reading!

Comment: If you shared the private key, you need to change wallet cause they can drain anything there. If not, you're good, just remove token approvals if you have any with https://revoke.cash/.

Comment: You cannot fetch the ETH or any other token back, if the contract doesn't have the functionality to do so.

Comment: It is a well known scam contract. The YT video is a scam, and all the comments are also fabricated. There's no such thing as a bot written in solidity. You should never deploy a contract that you do not understand. You have lost the ethers.